# Embedding UWP in Unity and vice versa?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, uwp, embed

I am building a disability service in Unity that will let paralyzed people move mouse cursor with their head movement only. Whatever is in Unity is just a function so im wondering if its possible to embed it in UWP software.

So someone would launch UWP software, click on "Start Unity" button and then the software would wrap itself into unity and function is now accessible (embedded software is clickable). There are a few examples of embedding browsers in Unity (example below), but can this be done with a software. Assuming I have access to software's code.

[Browser example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pnPpr.png)

Thank you!